# How do I handle/fix "Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure" when using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, mono, httpwebrequest, xamarin.ios

I am using MonoTouch to build an iPhone app.  In the app I am making Web Requests to pull back information from the web services running on our server.

This is my method to build the request:

```
public static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string serviceUrl, string methodName, JsonObject methodArgs)
{
    string body = "";

    body = methodArgs.ToString();

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.ContentLength = body.Length; // Set type to POST
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-JSON-RPC", methodName);

    StreamWriter strm = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    strm.Write(body);
    strm.Close();

    return request;
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
var request = CreateRequest(URL, METHOD_NAME, args);
request.BeginGetResponse (new AsyncCallback(ProcessResponse), request);
```

And ProcessResponse looks like this:

```
private void ProcessResponse(IAsyncResult result)
{

    try 
    {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

         using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result)) // this is where the exception gets thrown
         {
             using (StreamReader strm = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
             {
                 JsonValue value = JsonObject.Load(strm);

                 // do stuff...

                 strm.Close();
             } // using
             response.Close();
         } // using

         Busy = false;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Console.Error.WriteLine (e.Message);
     }
}
```

There is another question about this issue for Monodroid and the answer there suggested explicitly closing the output stream.  I tried this but it doesn't solve the problem.  I am still getting a lot of ReadDone2 errors occurring.

My workaround at the moment involves just re-submitting the Web Request if an error occurs and the second attempt seems to work in most cases.  These errors only happen when I am testing on the phone itself and never occur when using the Simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever possible try to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) since it will deal *automatically* with a lot of details (including streams). It also makes it easier to make your request **async** which is often helpful for not blocking the UI.

E.g. [`WebClient.UploadDataAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) looks like a good replacement for the above. You will get the data, when received from the `UploadDataCompleted` event (sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploaddatacompletedeventargs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Also are you sure your request is *always* and only using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` ? using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` is often usedm, by default, since it will represent more characters.

**UPDATE**: If you send or receive large amount to byte[] (or string) then you should look at using `OpenWriteAsync` method and `OpenWriteCompleted` event.

Comment: I haven't had time to come back to this yet.  I will try out WebClient and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Finally got a chance to have a proper look at this.  I have changed from using HttpWebRequests to using WebClient and after a bit of playing I haven't seen that error occur thus far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Mono, please see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19673