# RestSharp & MonoDroid: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, xamarin.android, restsharp

I have a similiar situation like this: [How do I handle/fix "Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure" when using MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830653/how-do-i-handle-fix-error-getting-response-stream-readdone2-receivefailure) but I'm only GETing a list, not posting anything in the body.

Furthermore, I'm using RestSharp, and it works in almost all the cases, but every once in a while I receive `Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure`.

What can possibly be the problem?

(ps: the exact same code on Wp7 doesn't cause any errors)

Comment: I get this sometimes too with MonoDroid. Exactly the same - I'm using RestSharp as well. 

Is the response chunked?

Comment: At the time, yes it was. Now it works completely. I changed nothing.

Comment: @SpiritMachine: And now I've got the error in a completely different web request.

Comment: I think it's a long standing bug in the Mono code. There was a previous release of Mono for Android (maybe Mono generally) that was supposed to rectify errors when reading chunked responses, but I'm really not sure if it addresses this specific case. I've never been able to get to the bottom of it and in all my searching have never found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19673) which appears to have a reproducible example. So, at the least, you could add yourself to the CC list for it.

(BTW, I get the error (also using restsharp) under Linux (Mint/17, Mono 3.2.8), so it is not specific to Android. It is hard to reproduce: for me it is simply happening after between 1000 and 10,000 web service calls, and it always works when restarting. I am not seeing a CPU or memory problem. It could be some buffer build-up, or might simply be a network failure, or even remote server problem?)